# Collapse a Drawer if a click is done on an active tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm discovering Material-UI and React, be kind with me if that's something silly, I'm learning. :)

I've a `Drawer` element and within this one a `Tabs` one wrapping several `Tab`. So far nothing fancy, I mostly took that from the official documentation, but the Drawer was added by me.

On my `Tabs` element I've an `onChange` attribute where I call a function to collapse/uncollapse the drawer when a tab is changed. I also change some content related to the tab.

The issue is that I would like to also collapse the drawer if the drawer is opened and that the user clicks on the already active/selected tab.

I tried to add an `onClick` event to the `Tabs` component as well, but then I had `onChange` triggering also the function I set for my `onClick` event.

Here's my current progress on a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-night-861569?file=/demo.tsx

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple useEffect should do the trick for you:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (value === 1) {
      setIsCollapsed(false);
    }
  }, [value]);
```

Also i've noticed in your code you're doing:

```
  const handleCollapse = () => {
    setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed);
  };
```

This is a bad practice in general. You can pass a callback function instead like so:

```
const handleCollapse = () => {
    setIsCollapsed(previousValue => !previousValue);
  };
```

Comment: Hey @hpertaia, thanks for your help and pointing out that bad practice. There's an issue with the useEffect part. If the drawer is opened after opening it via a click on the second tab, moving to the first tab will collapse the drawer. That's due to the fact that `value` here doesn't represent the active tab but just the index of the tab.

Comment: So I created a new state variable to store the old value of my tabs, it allows me to track the switch from one tab to the other within the useEffect you recommended. It works perfectly. Thanks for your help!